# Was it a fatal mistake to use wget in tails?

Tags: anonymity, tails

Using tor browser in tails I had a problem downloading some file.
So I used (as a kind of habit) `wget` to download the file (which succeeded).
Only after that I noticed that `wget` might have revealed by real IP address.

Or does tails provide special precautions against such user mistakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Tails will automatically wrap wget, curl, ssh, etc. with torsocks. The only thing that will give away your real IP is bittorrent which shouldn't be done on the Tor Network anyway.